# JavaScript regex for URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to run a JavaScript regex on URLs to detect any (one or more) special character after URL and put space before them, like:

```
url, --> url , or url), --> url ),
```

e.g.

(https://www.microsoft.com), into (https://www.microsoft.com ),

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I want becz url in my Doc with special char in end is not clickable, so adding one more space will solve my issue.

Comment: @Ashz what was the regex you used for matching URL's?

Comment: i don't have one i need to make, i would be great help if you can help in building the expression.

Comment: see here https://regex101.com/r/eX9yA4/1

Comment: Someone please help me with (JavaScript RegEx) i was trying to put one space ,when and only when there is one special character is there before url , like below example.

    ,www.google.com -->> , www.google.com

    ,https://www.google.com -->> , https://www.google.com

It shouldnt give space when its just only url no Special char.
There can be one or more character before url

-- Please help me ,i tried searching for exact question/topic but didnt find my answer ,so hopefuly not asking duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myregexp =/(\b(https?|ftp|file|http):\/\/[\-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[\-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/g;
var str="http://www.microsoft.com)"; //url
var res=myregexp.exec(str);          //execute regex query  
str=str.substring(0,myregexp.lastIndex)+' '+str.substring(myregexp.lastIndex);
```

I used Regex query for url from : https://stackoverflow.com/a/163684

Comment: Wondeful is worked for me , can you please also help me what else i need to add if i also need to remove protocol from url             e.g. "(https://www.google.com), convert to (www.google.com ),"  as in this requirement , space before comma issue is solved by your solution ,can you please also help me with removal of protocol ?

Comment: Many Thanks !!, is worked for me , can you please also help me what else i need to do to ,if i also need to remove protocol from url if url has "www." e.g. "https://www.google.com" , and keep it intact if it didnt have "www." e.g. "https://google.com" ,...............

Case1 : "(https://www.google.com), convert to (www.google.com ),"  
BUT IN 
Case2: "(https://google.com), convert to (https://google.com )," 

As in Case1 it removed https and added space before ")," but in Case2 it only added space before ")," and didnt removed "https://" from url.

Comment: Update Regarding Above ,its only working for first url in string doesnt works if many url in string.

Comment: http://ideone.com/ESKVH1
this extracts and gives the url without any special characters or whitespaces at start and end

Comment: keep executing the regex in loop to get next matches
A good guide :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec